# Traditional vs. Modern requirements elicitation. When each of them is more appropriate?

Tags: requirements

Traditional requirements elicitation: 
–  Interviewing customers and domain experts 
–  Questionnaires 
–  Observation 
–  Study of documents and software systems 

Modern requirements elicitation: 
–  Prototyping 
–  Brainstorming 
–  Joint Application Development (JAD) 
–  Rapid Application Development (RAD) 

When is it more appropriate to use modern or traditional? What kind of project? 
Spontaneously I think modern method is appropriate when we want to target the time to delivery on new project. And traditional method is more appropriate for upgrade project. Is there other situations which one of them is more appropriate than the other?

Comment: There are some issues with this question. First, RAD isn't requirements elicitation techniques but a process methodology for projects. Second, JAD is part of DSDM and defines the prototyping processes of that methodology. Third, it's making the assumption that there is a distinction between "traditional" and "modern" techniques, when they are simply tools that can and should be combined as appropriate - there's no reason why you can't interview domain experts, observe other people, brainstorm, and then create a prototype all during requirements elicitation activities.

Comment: I think your "Modern" description is way to vague. Having spent many years working at Traditional Requirements companies, I can tell you that Prototyping and Brainstorming are most certainly part of the "Traditional" techniques and RAD/JAD aren't even applicable in the context you are using them.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to these questions would require a very expensive and long term meta study on hundreds of various types of projects.  No two projects are a like and there are far too many variables--most of them random, unpredictable, and unseen--to try to correlate an approach with a type of project.  And I would bet the difference in validity of each approach is negligible.

The best answer I can see here is: depends.  What is the project, the experience of the team, the maturity level of both the organization and the project team, your project-specific constraints, and on and on.  Your best approach is one on which the team decides based on a cogent analysis of the benefits, costs, risks, and penalties of available alternatives.  What can be guaranteed, however, is that no matter what approach you use, your results will be less than perfect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. However as I stated in my assumption, if for example you want to target time in the delivery and you have few knowledge about the customer and what they wants. I would go for the modern method. the modern method would be perfect for a product proposal to get to the 2nd base. Clients attention. My assumption.

Comment: And you are certainly free to have such an assumption.  We all make decisions daily on these types of assumptions.  However, it is also prudent to research your assumption's validity.  There are countless examples of "truths" on which we operate, and pass down in training, that have zero validity.  And despite the science that shows it, they are tremendously hard to debunk; people hold on to them as if their lives depended on it.  Employee selection contains a lot of false beliefs.

Comment: Modern methods of requirements elicitation

Offer better insights at higher cost and effort

When high project risks (unc
lear objectives, undocumented 
procedures, unstable requirements, eroded user expertise, 
inexperienced developers, insufficient user commitment, etc.)

Include:
• Prototyping
• Brainstorming
• Joint Application Development (JAD)
• Rapid Application Development (RAD)- Pearson Education 2005, Chapter 2 (Maciaszek -- RASD 2/e)